# podman: disconnect rootless container from network

Tags: podman

Podman containers can be started with `--network=none` to deny any network access.  Running containers can be denied network access by disconnecting all networks according to `podman-network-disconnect(1)`.  However, for rootless containers this fails due to slirp4netns not being supported.  [This article](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/container-networking-podman) says the `podman network` commands are for rootful containers only.  (`podman-network(1)` does not.)

How can a running rootless container be denied network access?

Comment: Bearing in mind that there is no root access, if slirp4netns is ptrace(2)-able, one could use gdb to make it create a new user + network namespace and switch to it: all new sockets would fail (existing ones would continue to work). Probably irreversible. This is not a really reasonable approach, but can't think of anything else without privileges.

Comment: Just killing the `slirp4netns` process seems to be sufficient. That removes the `tap0` interface from the container. Seems better to just start with `--network=None`.

Comment: While I agree that killing the process is not generally the optimal solution I'd actually accept it as a working solution.